# PHP Function is echoing - but I only asked to `return`

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a small function for a WordPress site, and can't figure why my function is echoing the data on my webpage.

My function is:

```
function get_post_titles($args) {
    $titles = array();
    $posts = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($posts->have_posts()){
        $posts->the_post();
        $titles[] = the_title();
    }
    return $titles;
}
```

and I call it in a separate `.php` file:

```
<?php
$titles = get_post_titles($args);
?>
<select>
    <option selected="selected">Choose an Article</option>
    <?php
        foreach($titles as $title){
            ?> <option> $title </option><?php //this isn't working, pls ignore for this post
        }   
    ?>
</select>
...
```

The result is a webpage with a  Select box (yay!) but for some reason, the page also shows ALL of the titles in a row (it outputs the full array).

I would expect that if I had say, `echo get_post_titles($args)`, but nowhere in my code do I ask it to `echo`.  Why is my array visible?

I think it's because of my `$titles = get_post...` line.  But again, why is it displaying `$titles` instead of simply declaring/assigning the variable?

<sub>(I know there's a WordPress SE site, but I think this is more directly a PHP issue than WP issue.  However, if I should post over there instead, let me know).</sub>

Comment: Look at 3rd parameter https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) displays the title. You should use [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) instead.

Comment: Whelp that's exactly it! I studied my code for about an hour, and even learned yesterday about `get_the_[whatever]` vs `the_[whatever]` and completely overlooked that somehow...Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction! :D

Comment: My pleasure. As the other answer shows... many ways to skin a cat. I just prefer the lazy route, i.e. less typing, but both work.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wordpress Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title), following is the usage of `the_title`:

```
the_title( $before, $after, $echo );
```

> $echo
>       (Boolean) (optional) Display the title (TRUE) or return it for use in PHP (FALSE).
>
> Default: TRUE

You can do the following (set the third argument to `false`):

```
$titles[] = the_title('','',false);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the expanded info!

Comment: @BruceWayne happy to help :)